# Clean link on search filter php

Tags: php

I have a function to clean a link when I filter my search results

```
function cleanLink($url,$remove){
  $aQ = explode("&",str_replace("?", "", $url));
  foreach ($aQ as $part) {
    $pos = strpos($part, $remove);
    if ($pos === false)
        $queryClean[] = $part;
  }
  $line = implode("&", $queryClean);
  return "?".$line;
}

$linkACTUAL = "".$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];
cleanLink($linkACTUAL, "q=");
echo $linkACTUAL."&q=".$word;
```

This works fine, for example if my url is

```
www.mysite.com/?q=wordx
```

I want to add an "order alphabetic desc" so my url returns

```
www.mysite.com/?q=wordx&order=desc
```

but if my query string is empty (e.g. `www.mysite.com/`) the return is

```
www.mysite.com/?&q=word
```

How can I remove the `&` if the query string is empty?

Comment: Code formatting and readability (syntax polish)

Answer (score 0):

If your function is running fine when there are query string then you can simply put your function call inside if statement like

```
if(!empty($_GET))
{
  $linkACTUAL = "".$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];
  cleanLink($linkACTUAL, "q=");
  echo $linkACTUAL."&q=".$word;
}
```

Updated:

```
 echo  (false === strpos($linkACTUAL, "&"))  ? $linkACTUAL."q=".$word : $linkACTUAL."&q=".$word;
```

Comment: i alredy did this, but for example i m filter results by initial letter like mysite.com/?initial=a (i dont call the function) now my GET is not empty and then i want to filter using another letter like b, there i got mysite.com/?&initial=b.

Comment: @AlvaroLouzada please check the upated part.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if ($pos === false)
```

to

```
 if ($pos === false && $part)
```

to omit empty $part string (will evaluate as false). You also should initialize $queryClean

```
$queryClean = array();
```

Comment: still the same, return same result

Answer (score 0):

You can use parse_str and http_build_str to remove a parameter from the query string. You just to make sure pecl_http >= 0.23.0 is installed

```
function cleanLink($queryString, $remove)
{
    parse_str($queryString, $query);
    if (array_key_exists($remove, $query)) {
        unset($query[$remove]);
    }

    return http_build_str($query);
}

$linkACTUAL = $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];

cleanLink($linkACTUAL, "q");
echo $linkACTUAL . "&q=" . $word;
```

For more information see http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-str.php and http://php.net/manual/de/function.parse-str.php